# Bootstrap 4 split button full width

Tags: bootstrap-4

If you run this code snippet **full page**, you will see that the dropdown is left aligned with the caret and bleeds outside the container. If you run it where the screen size is as narrow as the container, then the dropdown is positioned below the "Save" button.

Q: Is there a way to have it always positioned underneath the "Save" button? I don't like it going outside the container. In fact, I should probably use text-right as it's class. If anything, I would like it to *end* at the right-hand border of the caret.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<form class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="btn-group float-right">
      <button name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <button name="Delete" class="dropdown-item btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just gotta add this class to your dropdown-menu bootstrap class: `dropdown-menu-right`

Did I do this right?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<form class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="btn-group float-right">
      <button name="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button name="Delete" class="dropdown-item btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```